how to avoid deadlock in process.wait
I'm looking for a way how to avoid or break the deadlock the docs warn about. Here is the warning:

This method [process.wait] can deadlock when using stdout=PIPE or
stderr=PIPE and the child process generates so much output that it
blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use the
communicate() method when using pipes to avoid this condition

The code looks basically like this:
proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
    program, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

# when the program generates a huge line,
# that is an error I want to handle
# with a program restart.

line = await proc.stdout.readline()

# readline() fails with: Separator is not found, and chunk exceed the limit
# the exception is caught and the handler kills the process:

proc.terminate()

# I checked that the PID does not exists any more

# but now this line (it's in a different task) blocks !!
await proc.wait()

The suggested communicate method is of no use in my case, the communication protocol is different.
I guess I should somehow discard the data from the pipe to unblock the mentioned buffer, but don't know how.

UPDATE:
I made a progress:

proc.returncode value gets filled in. That is just a detail, but it shows the process termination was registered.

a simple await proc.stdout.read() drains the buffer and unblocks the proc.wait()


Basically I have now a working solution, but new ideas would be still appreciated.

asyncio.wait can wait for multiple futures, unblocking when one or all return. So you can wait for output or termination at the same time. But I'm pretty sure you can also just wait for the stdout because it will indicate end-of-file when the process dies. You can then await the process itself, which should be instantaneous. asyncio.wait may still be useful if you also capture stderr

Your text mentions deadlock, but the comments in the code point to separator not found. It doesn't seem like a deadlock problem to me.

@tdelaney The "separator not found"  happens when a line produced by an external program exceeds the length limit. My program reacts to that condition and has a deadlock problem when that condition occurs. A process terminates, but process.wait() does not stop waiting for the termination.
